C#: Однострочное решение и цикл While
На вход с консоли пользователь вводит любое число от 0 до что-то около long.Max
Это число кладётся на левую чашу весов. Степенями тройки нужно сбалансировать эти весы.
Ну то есть если на вход даётся 7, то на левые к 7 кладём 3, а на правые 9 и 1.
Веса не могут повторяться. То есть нельзя дважды класть 1.
Цель, решить данную задачу в одну, максимально короткую строку. Не важно насколько она будет не читабельной.
Пока что я смог дойти вот до такого трёхстрочного решения :
List<List<long>> weights = new List<List<long>> { new List<long> { long.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) }, new List<long>() };
while (weights[0].Sum() != weights[1].Sum()) weights[weights[0].Sum() > weights[1].Sum() ? 1 : 0].Add((long)Math.Pow(3, ((Func<long, long, bool>)((number, power) => number > (long)((Math.Pow(3, power) - 1) / 2)))(weights[0].Sum() > weights[1].Sum() ? weights[0].Sum() - weights[1].Sum() : weights[1].Sum() - weights[0].Sum(), ((Func<long, long>)(number => (long)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(number, 3))))(weights[0].Sum() > weights[1].Sum() ? weights[0].Sum() - weights[1].Sum() : weights[1].Sum() - weights[0].Sum())) ? ((Func<long, long>)(number => (long)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(number, 3))))(weights[0].Sum() > weights[1].Sum() ? weights[0].Sum() - weights[1].Sum() : weights[1].Sum() - weights[0].Sum()) : ((Func<long, long>)(number => (long)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(number, 3))))(weights[0].Sum() > weights[1].Sum() ? weights[0].Sum() - weights[1].Sum() : weights[1].Sum() - weights[0].Sum()) - 1));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(weights));

Полагаю, что желаемого можно достичь используя метод Agreggate из Linq или используя лямбды, но сильно смущает наличие while. Возможно ли с ним что-то сделать?
Вот изначальное моё решение, которое я пытаюсь ужать до одной строки :
 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
             long weight = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             List<List<long>> weights = new List<List<long>>
             {
                 new List<long>(),
                 new List<long>()
             };
             weights[0].Add(weight);
             FindThreeDegreeWeights(weights);
             Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(weights));            
     }

     static long MinPowerOfThreeNotLessThan(long number)
     {
         long power = (long)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(number, 3));
         return power;
     }

     static bool IsNumberGreaterThanSumOfPreviousPowersOfThree(long number, long power)
     {
         long sum = (long)((Math.Pow(3, power) - 1) / 2);
         return number > sum;
     }

     static void FindThreeDegreeWeights(List<List<long>> weights)
     {
         long leftSum = weights[0].Sum();
         long rightSum = weights[1].Sum();

         if (leftSum == rightSum)
             return;

         if (leftSum > rightSum)
         {
             long difference = leftSum - rightSum;
             long upperDegree = MinPowerOfThreeNotLessThan(difference);
             if (IsNumberGreaterThanSumOfPreviousPowersOfThree(difference, upperDegree))
             {
                 weights[1].Add((long)Math.Pow(3, upperDegree));
             }
             else
             {
                 weights[1].Add((long)Math.Pow(3, upperDegree - 1));
             }
         }
         else
         {
             long difference = rightSum - leftSum;
             long upperDegree = MinPowerOfThreeNotLessThan(difference);
             if (IsNumberGreaterThanSumOfPreviousPowersOfThree(difference, upperDegree))
             {
                 weights[0].Add((long)Math.Pow(3, upperDegree));
             }
             else
             {
                 weights[0].Add((long)Math.Pow(3, upperDegree - 1));
             }
         }
         FindThreeDegreeWeights(weights);
     }
 }


Это перевод числа в троичную систему счисления.

Не совсем троичную. Знаковую троичную, т. е. числа -1, 0 и 1.

@rotabor Там вопрос совсем удалён, я обычно удалённые вопросы вижу. Что ж там было такое )

@rotabor, надо было на codegolf спрашивать, а не на SO - там такое считают оффтопиком сейчас.

@CrazyElf, обыкновенно он удалён, просто на enSO, а не на ruSO.

@Qwertiy А, тупанул я. На английском у меня нет столько репутации, чтобы удалённые вопросы видеть, всё понятно )

Делал от балды, чисто ради интереса, даже немного с нейронкой, поэтому не ответ, но вдруг на идею подтолкнет.

Спасибо OP за интересную задачку.

ОБНОВЛЕНО
Вот решение в одну строку по алгоритму @MBo (но я его сам придумал):
using System;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        for (long i = 1, n = Int64.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), j = n % 3; n > 0; i += i << 1, n = n / 3 + (j == 0 ? 0 : j - 1), j = n % 3 ) if (j > 0) Console.WriteLine(i * ((j << 1) - 3));
    }
}

Если степень тройки в ответе положительная, то кладётся вместе с числом.
Можно и с применением Linq:
using System;
using System.Linq;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        foreach (var m in Enumerable.Range(Int64.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!) is long N && 1L is long i? 0 : 0, 40)
            .Select(s => new { x = N = Math.DivRem(N, 3, out long j), Rem = j, y = j == 0 ? N : N += j - 1 })
            .Where(w => w.Rem > 0).Select(s => (i *= 3) / 3 * ((s.Rem << 1) - 3))) Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
}


Если исключить список как лишнюю сущность, то даже одна строка получится (по методу подсчёта строк автора): for (long i = 1, n = Int64.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), j; n > 0; i *= 3) { j = n % 3; n /= 3; if (j > 0) { Console.WriteLine(i * (j * 2 - 3)); n += j - 1; } }

Вероятно однострочник имелось в виду в одну ; через Linq и синтаксис выражений без блоков кода. Иначе смысл? Отформатировать тест кода в одну строку это не проблема.

@aepot Есть такое. Создание анонимного типа не будет же считаться?

Решения вполне себе читабельные и понятные.

@rotabor - спасибо. Да. Думаю такой ответ подойдёт. Формально ; в цикле for вроде как за отдельную строчку не считаются. Хотя конечно это тема для отдельного холивара.

Само собой, от if там тоже можно избавиться, если что.

@aepot А зачем вы удалили свой ответ? Там есть интересные приёмы.

@aepot Хорошо зашло, я даже статью на Хабр написал.

Может, полезно будет: целочисленный алгоритм перевода в уравновешенную троичную систему на Python (нули убрал)
def TriEqSystem(n):
    lst = []
    p = 1
    while n:
        n, m = divmod(n, 3)
        if m:
            lst.append(p*(3-2*m))  #добавляет p или (-p) для остатков 1 и 2
            n += (m-1)             #увеличить следующий разряд для остатка 2
        p *= 3
    return lst

for i in range(1,101):
    l = TriEqSystem(i)
    print(i, sum(l), l)

...
10 10 [1, 9]
11 11 [-1, 3, 9]
12 12 [3, 9]
13 13 [1, 3, 9]
14 14 [-1, -3, -9, 27]
15 15 [-3, -9, 27]
16 16 [1, -3, -9, 27]
17 17 [-1, -9, 27]
...


Хорошо зашло, я даже статью на Хабр написал.
